# Como Guardar\Ler lista encadeada em arquivo?

Tags: c, arquivo, lista

sou bem iniciante em programação e estou codificando esse programa para um trabalho de faculdade.

É um "gerenciador de pizzaria", preciso guardar\ler uma lista encadeada (cadastro dos clientes) num arquivo, de maneira que não se perca os dados quando o programa for encerrado.

Mas como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: A dúvida é sobre como ler/escrever num arquivo, ou sobre como serializar/desserializar a lista encadeada para gravar como texto?

Comment: Seria importante também você [edit] a pergunta para mostrar como estruturou sua lista encadeada no programa.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode escrever os dados em um vetor ou em uma Struct, depende da implementação que você vai fazer, coloquei algumas referencias no fim da resposta.

veja um exemplo de como escrever um vetor de inteiros no arquivo

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    main() {
        FILE *arq;
        // Esses dados vão ser gravados !
        int ret, vet[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        // arquivo alvo
        char nomearq[] = "vet.dat";
        // arquivo tem que ter permissão w para escrita e b para abrir como binario
        arq = fopen(nomearq, "wb");
        if (arq != NULL) {
            // aqui é feita a escrita !!
            ret = fwrite(vet, sizeof(int), 10, arq);
            if (ret == 10)
                printf("Gravacao com sucesso\n");
            else
                printf("Foram gravados apenas %d elementos\n", ret);
            fclose(arq);
        }
        else
            puts("Erro: criacao do arquivo");
    }
```

Você pode recuperar os dados escritos no primeiro exemplo dessa forma

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    main() {
        FILE *arq;
        int i, ret, vet[10];
        char nomearq[] = "vet.dat";

        arq = fopen(nomearq, "rb");
        if (arq != NULL) {
            // estou recuperando AQUI
            ret = fread(vet, sizeof(int), 10, arq);
            if (ret == 10) {
                printf("Elementos: ");
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    printf("%d ", vet[i]);
            }
            else
                printf("Foram lidos apenas %d elementos\n", ret);
            fclose(arq);
        }
        else
            puts("Erro: abertura do arquivo");
    }
```

Você pode guardar estruturas mais complexas usando struct, exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>

    const int na = 6;

    typedef struct {
        char nome[10];
        int nota;
    } tp_aluno;

main() {
    tp_aluno alunos[] = {{"Luiz", 5}, {"Paulo", 5}, {"Maria", 3},
                         {"Luiza", 4}, {"Felipe", 8}, {"Fabiana", 6}};
    int ret;
    FILE *arq;
    char nomearq[] = "turma.dat";
    arq = fopen(nomearq, "wb");
    if (arq != NULL) {
        ret = fwrite(alunos, sizeof(tp_aluno), na, arq);
        if (ret == na)
            printf("Gravacao %d registros com sucesso\n", ret);
        else
            printf("Foram gravados apenas %d elementos\n", ret);
        fclose(arq);
    }
    else
        puts("Erro: abertura do arquivo");
}
```

Para recuperar os dados você pode fazer assim

```
#include <stdio.h>

    const int na = 6;

    typedef struct {
        char nome[10];
        int nota;
    } tp_aluno;

main() {
    tp_aluno alunos[na];
    int i, ret;
    FILE *arq;
    char nomearq[] = "turma.dat";

    arq = fopen(nomearq, "rb");
    if (arq != NULL) {
        ret = fread(alunos, sizeof(tp_aluno), na, arq);
        if (ret == na) {
            printf("Lidos %d registros com sucesso\n", ret);
            for (i = 0; i < ret; i++)
                printf("%s %d\n", alunos[i].nome, alunos[i].nota);
        }
        else
            printf("Foram lidos apenas %d elementos\n", ret);
        fclose(arq);
    }
    else
        puts("Erro: abertura do arquivo");
}
```

Como todo trabalho de faculdade, exige pesquisa e esforço, você pode consultar os comandos [arquivos](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~joaoreis/Site%20de%20tutoriais/c_int/arquivos.htm#intro) e [Struct](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~joaoreis/Site%20de%20tutoriais/c_int/estruturas.htm#declarando)

Answer (score 1):

Pode tentar usar uma função semelhante a mostrada abaixo:

```
/**
 * Insere um novo registro no arquivo especificado. A função SEMPRE 
 * insere o novo registro no final do arquivo, assim os dados
 * anteriores sempre são preservados.
 *
 * @param char *file string com o nome do arquivo que você quer inserir.
 * @param void *data struct com os dados que você deseja inserir.
 * @param size_t len tamanho da struct com os dados a inserir.
 * @return  void
 *
 * @example para usar essa função basta chamá-la da seguinte forma:
 * fileInsert("ArquivoInserido.dat", &structComDados, sizeof(structComDados));
 * 
 * @author Renato Tavares <dr.renatotavares@gmail.com>
 * @version   1.0
 *
 */

void fileInsert(char *file, void *data, size_t len) {

    FILE *filePtr;

    if ((filePtr = fopen(file, "rb+")) == NULL) {
        printf("Arquivo %s não pode ser aberto.", file);
        exit(EPERM);

    } else {

        fseek(filePtr, 0L, SEEK_END);
        fwrite(data, len, 1, filePtr);
        fclose(filePtr);
    }
}
```

Também é um trabalho de faculdade, neste gits você pode encontrar o conjunto de funções completas, bastante coisa já pronta e até bem documentado.

https://gist.github.com/RenatoTavares/7834642

Comment: E para ler os dados?